# How to pass an array to a HttpGet using Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

Okay so I'm trying to make a front-end filter for a list of search results (much like Amazon), where the user can select a filter category and multiple filter options.

So for example, I have a result list of employees. One of the things you can filter by is by the first letter of the last name. So when you go to the filter, you're presented with a list of checkboxes and a corresponding letter: A[] B[] C[] ... Z[].

The user can select any combination of A-Z, and when they hit submit, I want the route to look like www.sitename.com?lastname=A&lastname=C&lastName=F etc etc using a GET form.

Is there a way in Razor to tie a List/array variable to all of the checked boxes on so that it can post on submit?

Comment: You might want to look at [How to make Check Box List in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778489/how-to-make-check-box-list-in-asp-net-mvc/37779070#37779070)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index"))
{
    <label><input name="lastname" type="checkbox" value="A" />A</label>
    <label><input name="lastname" type="checkbox" value="C" />C</label>
    <label><input name="lastname" type="checkbox" value="F" />F</label>
    <button type="button" onclick="var form=$(this).closest('form');form.attr('action', '@Url.Action("Index")?' + form.serialize());form.submit();">Submit</button>
}
```