# Pass complex object from view to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, request

I have this model:

```
public class MyClassVM
{
public Product MyProduct { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Dog> MyDogs { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have this action in a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyClassVM)
{
//do something...
}
```

I have an html view and have been for a while trying to bind the object and send it from the view to the controller as a parameter but I've not been able yet...
Which is the correct way to do this?

```
 <form method="post" action="MyController/MyAction">


   @{ foreach (var dog in Model.MyDogs)
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="[@i].MyDogs" /></td>
    </tr>

}
    <input type="hidden" name="MyProduct" value="@Model.MyProduct"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

But when it arrives to the controller is always null... I've checked the request using Dev Tools and the data is not being bound correctly. I would probably need to `serialize` the object to `Json` format in my view???

Comment: You might want to convert `IEnumerable<Dog> MyDogs` to `IList<SelectListItem> MyDogs` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778489/how-to-make-check-box-list-in-asp-net-mvc/37779070#37779070).

Comment: MyProduct is bound, but myDogs are not?

Comment: both of them are not being bound, but at this moment I think I found a solution for `myDogs`, however MyProduct is not being bound for now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind a complex object to an `<input>`. Both post back a single value.

Your checkbox posts back `"on"` if its checked and nothing if its not (because it does not have a `value` attribute) which cannot be bound to typeof `Dog`. And if you inspect the value attribute for the hidden input you will see that it is `value="yourAssembly.Product"` which again cannot be bound to typeof `Product`.

You need to generate a form control for each property of each `Dog` in the collection, and a form control for each property of `Product`.

A typical example based on the following models

```
public class Dog
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.MyDogs.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyDogs[i].ID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyDogs[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyDogs[i].IsSelected, Model.MyDogs[i].Name)
}
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyProduct.ID)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyProduct.Name)
```

Note that your `MyDogs` needs to implement `IList`, otherwise you need to use an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Dog` (refer [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for more detail).

Note also that if your not editing any properties of `Product`, then do not include any form controls for it - just get the `Product` again in the POST method if you need it.