# How to use checkboxes for batch operation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-modal

Say I have a view like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assign">
    Assign
</button>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var employee in ViewBag.employees)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="@employee.Id" /></td>
            <td>@employee.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="assign" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Assign employee to group</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- a dropdown of groups -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Assign</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have a controller to call:

```
public ActionResult Assign(List<int> employeeIds, int groupId)
```

How can I get the list of `Id`s that are checked and the `groupId` from the dropdown in modal, so that I can call the controller?

For example if the data look like this

```
0. Alice
1. Bob
2. Charlie
3. Dan
```

And I checked Bob and Charlie and want to assign them to group 1, so the `employeeId`s will be 1 and 2, and `groupId` will be 1.

Comment: You checkbox does not have a`name` attribute so it does not post back a value. Change it to `<input type="checkbox" name="value="employeeIds" "@employee.Id" />`. But I suggest you look at [Pass List of Checkboxes into View and Pull out IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) to do this correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `for` loop instead of `foreach`. Besides, I suggest to use `ViewModel` instead of `ViewBag`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Employees.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Employees[i].Checked)</td>
            <td>@Model.Employees[i].Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

### Model

You want to rename `ViewModel` something meaningful.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel
        {
            Employees = new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee {Id=1, Name = "John", Checked = true},
                new Employee {Id=2, Name = "Eric", Checked = false}
            }
        };
        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ViewModel vm)
    {
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37779070/296861) is another way.

Comment: Well, I need to get the groupId from the dropdown as well. The goal is to assign employees to groups.

Comment: it does not help. I know how to get checked items. What I am asking is how to get the list of checked items in the page and the group from modal together so I can call the controller `Assign(List<int> employeeIds, int groupId)`

Comment: @JayTang You need to use Ajax.