# How to get values of selected items id in CheckBox in ASP.NET CORE?

Tags: asp.net-core, checkbox, insert, multi-table

I have 3 table. first one for Movie , second one for Category, third one(MovieCategor) its hold MovieId and Category Id

I want to insert Movie and choose the category. I list to category like checkbox to page View.  How to make insert for Movie and MovieCategor table?

View Page -

```
 <ul style="list-style-type: none">
                        @foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
                        {
                            <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="@category.Id" name="Id" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">@category.CategoryName</label>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
```

Controller -

```
public IActionResult Create(MovieCreateViewModel movieCreateViewModel,int[] Id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string fileName = UploadFile(movieCreateViewModel);
                Movie movie = new Movie()
                {
                    Name = movieCreateViewModel.Name,
                    Director = movieCreateViewModel.Director,
                    Summary = movieCreateViewModel.Summary,
                    Banner = fileName,
                    MoviesCategory = movieCreateViewModel.MoviesCategories
                };
                foreach (var id  in Id)
                {
                    MoviesCategory moviesCategory = new MoviesCategory();

                    moviesCategory.CategoryId = id;
                    moviesCategory.MovieId = movie.Id;
                    
                    _movieCategoryService.Add(moviesCategory);
                }
                _movieService.Add(movie);
                return RedirectToAction("List");
            }

            return View();
        }
}
```

Comment: they'll map to bools.  Include your Movie and MovieCategory models.  If I understand correctly you may want a many-to-many relationship here.

Comment: Yes I did many-to-many relationship but how to get Category Id on view page ? So if I make checkbox button of value ıd can I get the category Id ?

Comment: Check this post's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778489/how-to-make-check-box-list-in-asp-net-mvc/37779070  In your case the values would be the ids.  So you'll get back a List<int> of categoryIDs which you can iterate through to make the database entries.  (I believe any unchecked values will not be returned... asp.net sort of ignores false bools in forms...)

Comment: @pcalkins thank you for your helping.. I figure out and. it's worked :)